# How to find objects with inner objects having multiple fields by specific values in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with objects named "DynamicFields" and each of them have inner objects named "Fields" like this:

```
 {
                "DynamicFields": [
                    {
                        "Fields": [
                            {
                                "DFieldVal": "Value1",
                                "Owned": 0,
                                "DFieldRelCode": 181254,
                                "DFieldCode": 1835
                            },
                            {
                                "DFieldVal": "Value2",
                                "Owned": 0,
                                "DFieldRelCode": 181255,
                                "DFieldCode": 1836
                            },
                            {
                                "DFieldVal": "Value3",
                                "Owned": 1,
                                "DFieldRelCode": 181256,
                                "DFieldCode": 1837
                            },
                            {
                                "DFieldVal": "Value4",
                                "Owned": 0,
                                "DFieldRelCode": 181257,
                                "DFieldCode": 1838
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I need to find objects "DynamicFields" that has inner objects "Fields" with this exact values:

"DFieldCode": 1837

and

"Owned": 0

Im using this query for it, but it gives me wrong result, it should return an empty result because there isn't any inner object "Fields" having both of the values:

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":10,
  "query": {
    "bool":{
        "must":[
            { "terms": { "DynamicFields.Fields.Owned" : [0] } },
            { "terms": { "DynamicFields.Fields.DFieldCode" : [1837] } }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

I think the problem is that Elastic search sees the inner objects properties as normal property for the Root Object so it returns the objects that have the mentioned fields in all inner objects no matter in the same inner object.

EDIT:
i have summarized the data to make it simpler
the mapping is full map of the data:

```
{
"marketplace": {
    "mappings": {
        "object": {
            "properties": {
                "Addresses": {
                    "properties": {
                        "AddrID": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "AddressText": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "AddressTree": {
                            "properties": {
                                "AddrFieldRelID": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "AddrTitleName": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "AddrTitlePersianName": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "AddrValName": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "Latitude": {
                                    "type": "float"
                                },
                                "Longitude": {
                                    "type": "float"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "Latitude": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "Longitude": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "Tel": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "DelFlag": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "DynamicFields": {
                    "properties": {
                        "DynamicDefCode": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "DynamicDefDataTypeName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "DynamicDefName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "DynamicValKind": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "Fields": {
                            "properties": {
                                "DFieldCode": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "DFieldRelCode": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "DFieldVal": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "Owned": {
                                    "type": "boolean"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "GFRefCode": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "GoodsDesc": {
                    "properties": {
                        "FName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "GoodsFullName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "Supplier": {
                            "properties": {
                                "Barcode": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "GPackDayPrice": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "GoodsEnterDate": {
                                    "type": "date"
                                },
                                "GoodsFinalCode": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "GoodsFullName": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "GoodsWHStock": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "StoreName": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "UserName": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "WHName": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "WareHouseCode": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "UserName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "GoodsFinalCode": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "Images": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IsMainObject": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "ObjectDetailPackID": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "ObjectKind": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "Prices": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Barcode": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "GPWeight": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "GpackDayPrice": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "PackingName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "RefGoodsFinalCode": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "TreePath": {
                    "properties": {
                        "DFieldCode": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "DFieldRelCode": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "DFieldVal": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of field `Fields`? Is it `object` or `nested`?

Comment: Sorry im new in elastic search, i dont know the difference between object and nested

Comment: Can you add mapping of index? Use `GET <index>/_mappings`

Comment: i didnt add any mapping to the index while creating it, you think the problem is the index mapping?

Comment: Sorry my bad it should be `_mapping` and not `_mappings`

Comment: map is added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your index shows you saved your array as an object,
read more about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Basically unless specified otherwise elasticsearch flattens arrays when being saved, making objects in arrays lose their structure.
you should define the type of Fields as nested to avoid this.